# wanted to understand the currency field behavior

Tags: administration, fields, multi-currency, currency

We have a custom object and it has a field lets say PrevYrTPC and it is of type currency.
I was going through the records of the current object and I found something which I could not understand.
The Value in the field PrevYrTPC of record A shows as **USD 7.175,28 (EUR 5.905,254)** and the value in another record B shows as **EUR 10,040.**

I wanted to understand why is the values of the same field showing in different formats for different records.

We wanted to see the value in all records in the format of EUR(some value) only.

current set up of org and user:

- Currency on my User is set to EUR - EURO
- Corporate Currency U.S. Dollar in company information of the org

Comment: Have you looked at the actual Currency field (CurrencyISOCode) for those records?

Answer (score 1):

This is covered someplace in the help. If you have any automation that executes on your object, that code needs to take into the consideration the ISO code and/or User Locale settings to determine which currency the transaction has been saved in. Otherwise, the code will assume it's in the default currency. This is especially important when it comes to Opportunity roll-up triggers.

These types of discrepancies can also be related to how you've configured your currency exchange rates, especially whether you've enabled advanced currency management. Dated exchange rates can simplify currency management by allowing a start and end date for a specific exchange rate as opposed to using a daily rate for a transaction.